# Limit of the summand

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I learnt that if $\displaystyle\lim\limits_{x\mathop\to\infty}f(x) \ne 0$ or if the limit does not exist then $\displaystyle\sum_{x\mathop=1}^{\infty}f(x)$ diverges.

But suppose $f(x)$ takes the value of $0$ at every integer, and the value of $1$ everywhere else. Then the sum clearly converges to $0$, but the limit of the function does not exist. So isn't the statement incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement is indeed false, for the reason you've given.

Correct would be: if $\lim \limits_{x\to \infty}(f(x))\neq 0$ or $\lim \limits_{\substack{{x\to \infty}\\ x\in \mathbb N}}(f(x))$ doesn't exist, then $\displaystyle \sum \limits_{n=1}^\infty\left(f(n)\right)$ diverges.

Comment: What's the difference apart from changing a letter?

Comment: @LuciusTarquiniusSuperbus Many apologies, I misread your question. give me a minute to explain what's going on.

Comment: @LuciusTarquiniusSuperbus Fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

Your confusion is between the ideas of *necessary* and *sufficient* conditions. Note the differerence:

If the limit is non-zero then the sum diverges.

If the sum diverges then the limit is non-zero.

These two statemnts are very different. That first one means that a non-zero limit is a sufficient condition for divergence. However, it is not a necessary condition; the second statement is untrue. Consider the series $\sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{1}{n}$ diverges, which diverges, and yet $\frac{1}{n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: There is no confusion. The $f$ the OP provided is a counter example.

Comment: I don't see how I've confused necessary and sufficient conditions. I've found a function whose limit does not converge to 0 whose sum converges, which is a counterexample.

Comment: @LuciusTarquiniusSuperbus The way your question is phrased, i.e. starting the sentence with "*But*", lead me to believe that you thought that your example disproved the original, correct, statement.

Answer (score -2):

i think that the statement "if $\displaystyle\lim\limits_{x\mathop\to\infty}f(x) \ne 0$ or if the limit does not exist then $\displaystyle\sum_{x\mathop=1}^{\infty}f(x)$ diverges" only applies to continuous functions or discrete functions defined at Integers.

Comment: Even assuming continuity this is wrong.

Comment: I think everybody dropped the ball on this one. What Superbus seems to be describing is the divergence test, which goes something like this ... "if $\displaystyle\lim\limits_{k\mathop\to\infty}a_k \ne 0$ or if the limit does not exist then $\displaystyle\sum_{k\mathop=1}^{\infty}a_k$ diverges". Clearly, it's a statement about discrete sequences, not about continuous functions.